# Callback never be invoked when I excute a asynchronous transaction with Realm

Tags: android, realm

I use Realm in my Android app.
When I excute a asynchronous transaction to save my object,I find that callback never be invoked sometimes.The Thread is Android main thread.And there is no exception be caught.
What's wrong?
There is my code:

```
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        Log.i("ysd", "thread:"+Thread.currentThread());
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                Log.i("ysd", "copyToRealmOrUpdate");
                bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(t);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i("ysd", "Realm——onSuccess");
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onOk();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("ysd", "Realm:" + e.getMessage() + "," +     e.getCause());
                // transaction is automatically rolled-back, do any cleanup here
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onError(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("ysd", "Realm_Exception:" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: probably cause of listener is null, better to post code with listener initialization.

Comment: The `Realm` instance is closed after the try catch block. The current logic is if the Realm instance is closed, the `onSuccess` won't be posted to the calling looper. But I do think you user case makes sense. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1893 , we are discussing should the `onSuccess` be posted alway? Before we change the behaviour (maybe), you can just control the life cycle with your `Activity` or `Fragment` or something else, to ensure `onSuccess` will be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a discussion about this user case, and we think it is better to keep current behavior.

To make sure the `onSuccess` will be called after transaction finished, you need:

1. The Realm instance which starts this transaction is not closed. **This is the reason of your question. try-catch block will close Realm instance when it finishes.**
2. The `RealmAsyncTask` is not canceled.
3. The caller's looper thread is still running.